# Could not read from TensorArray index 0. Possible you are working with resizeable TensorArray. stop_gradients isn't allowing gradients to be written

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to reproduce the multi-gpu version of the code, with little change in the model architecture of ResNet (rest same) as given here https://github.com/FlyEgle/keras-yolo3. under train_height_point.py. 
direct link : https://github.com/FlyEgle/keras-yolo3/blob/master/train_height_point.py

Error seems to be in the Yolo_loss function

I have tried modifying the while_loop and other tricks mentioned in other stackoverflow solutions 
[Gradients error using TensorArray Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416000/gradients-error-using-tensorarray-tensorflow)
[TensorArray TensorArray_1_0: Could not read from TensorArray index 0 because it has not yet been written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139446/tensorarray-tensorarray-1-0-could-not-read-from-tensorarray-index-0-because-it)
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3663

When I run the code, I get the following error on the 1st epoch

```
Train on 62880 samples, val on 6976 samples, with batch size 1.
Epoch 1/400
2019-06-28 18:39:30.247036: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at tensor_array_ops.cc:661 : Invalid argument: TensorArray replica_0/model_3/yolo_loss/TensorArray_3: Could not read from TensorArray index 0.  Furthermore, the element shape is not fully defined: [?,?,3].  It is possible you are working with a resizeable TensorArray and stop_gradients is not allowing the gradients to be written.  If you set the full element_shape property on the forward TensorArray, the proper all-zeros tensor will be returned instead of incurring this error.
2019-06-28 18:39:30.251868: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at tensor_array_ops.cc:661 : Invalid argument: TensorArray replica_0/model_3/yolo_loss/TensorArray_1_4: Could not read from TensorArray index 0.  Furthermore, the element shape is not fully defined: [?,?,3].  It is possible you are working with a resizeable TensorArray and stop_gradients is not allowing the gradients to be written.  If you set the full element_shape property on the forward TensorArray, the proper all-zeros tensor will be returned instead of incurring this error.
2019-06-28 18:39:30.251942: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at tensor_array_ops.cc:661 : Invalid argument: TensorArray replica_0/model_3/yolo_loss/TensorArray_2_5: Could not read from TensorArray index 0.  Furthermore, the element shape is not fully defined: [?,?,3].  It is possible you are working with a resizeable TensorArray and stop_gradients is not allowing the gradients to be written.  If you set the full element_shape property on the forward TensorArray, the proper all-zeros tensor will be returned instead of incurring this error.
2019-06-28 18:39:31.368047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 517, in <module>
    _main()
  File "train.py", line 177, in _main
    callbacks=[logging, lr_schedule, checkpoint]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1217, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray replica_0/model_3/yolo_loss/TensorArray_3: Could not read from TensorArray index 0.  Furthermore, the element shape is not fully defined: [?,?,3].  It is possible you are working with a resizeable TensorArray and stop_gradients is not allowing the gradients to be written.  If you set the full element_shape property on the forward TensorArray, the proper all-zeros tensor will be returned instead of incurring this error.
     [[{{node replica_0/model_3/yolo_loss/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3}}]]
     [[{{node loss/add_20}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the stacktrace above, you need to pass a parameter named `element_shape` with fully defined like `element_shape(10, 10, 10)` instead of `None` or `element_shape=(None, 10, 10)`. It seems that there could not be a **unknown dimension**.

I also have this problem, and try to find a better way to solve it.